# Get source location of mock definition (rspec)

Tags: rspec, mocking

I search for a way to retrive the source location of an mock definition. E.g. I would like to have something like this in rspec:

```
describe "mocking AnyObj" do
  before(:each) do
    @x = Object.new
    @x.stub(:fkt)
  end

  it "should return source location of @x.stub(:fkt)" do
     @x.method(:fkt).source_location[1].should == 4
  end
end
```

The reason for this is to provide a means to debug rspec files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. `source_location` is defined for a `Method` which is returned by `method`, as follows:

```
describe "mocking AnyObj" do
  before(:each) do
    @x = Object.new
    @x.stub(:fkt)
  end

  it "should show source location" do
     @x.method(:fkt).source_location[1].should == 4
  end
end
```

Note you also had `x.stub(:fkt)` instead of `@x.stub(:fkt)`.

Finally, though, note that you're getting a line number from the `method_double.rb` file (at least in the version of RSpec that I checked) which shows the line number where the actual stub definition occurs (e.g. class evaluation of `def fkt ....` or some such). There's no way to refer the line within your test from where `stub` was called.

Comment: Thanks, that's closer. I think that I can't easily get the source location by the way method_double.rb creates the stub.

Comment: What source location are you looking for?

Comment: The line with @x.stub(:fkt).

Comment: But that's not where the mock is defined. That's where you _call_ the `stub` method in RSpec _from_ your spec. The only source locations that are available, as far as I know, are where actual method definitions occur.